# what is "COPY . /src"for when building a image

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker,I'm reading the docker's documentation.
there is a simple example in it

https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/

https://github.com/enokd/docker-node-hello/

I'm confused about this"COPY . /src"in the Dockerfile.

In this example, "." represent the directory where the Dockerfile is in(the current dir,in my computer,it is /home/pete),So why do I have to copy all the files in /home/pete to /src?(does this what the instruction mean?)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you build a new image, you create a specific directory, where you put all what you will need for this specific image, your Dockerfile, the files you want to add...

If you have 20 Tera of data in /home/pete, your build will be very long, with no reason

Edit: you will see "uploading context", which means docker reads and compresses all files in /home/pete and in all your subdirectories...

Comment: thank you for your answering.
so,in the example https://github.com/enokd/docker-node-hello/
just because 'Dockerfile' is not created in '/src',the instruction"COPY . /src"
is need?In this example if I just create ' Dockerfile 'in side '/src'(the spesific dir as what you said),I don't need this 'COPY' instruction any more?

Comment: No , that means that you want to copy all your local files (`.`) in the /src directory of your image. You need the vagrant file, the index.js and the package.json.  When you build, a good habit is to use a tag, `docker build -t myappli_v1 .` or any significant name

Comment: to figure out what the image need is really important,so I just  care about this "copy" instruction.
In this example I think the index.js and the package.json were created in '/src'.so I don't need to copy anything.
Then my question is "if I also created 'Dockerfile' in '/src',do I need any copy instruction?"

Answer (score 1):

[COPY](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) copies files from the host directory (where host is a system running the docker) to the docker container. You might well want to start with [Docker's tutorial](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/) - easy to read and will save you some time.

**edit**

Technically in the examples you show you don't need to copy *all* of the contents of the current directory to the container - you would be just fine with just `index.js` and `package.json`, but the authors copy `.` for the simplicity sake.

Comment: thank you for your advise~
in this example,is '/src' the host dir?
so,if i just create 'Dockerfile' inside this dir,Do I need this instruction any more?

Comment: Docker build will not carry files of the directory containing the Dockerfile by default. So yes, if you need those files.

Comment: sorry..I don't get 'yes' for what.....
you mean,If I created the 'Dockerfile' inside the dir '/src' which contains what the image needs,I can remove the "copy . /src" in this example.
is this what you meaning?

Comment: thank you ,in this example,did the author actually only want the Dockerfile in current directory by using 'copy . /src'?

Comment: Usually, you will create a directory `mkdir my_app`, then `cd my_app`, then create a Dockerfile, then copy the remaining files needed by the COPY in my Dockerfile, and then I can do `docker build -t=myapp_v1 .`